# Removing trusted testers from chrome webstore extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Am trying to publish my extension to trusted testers. (as described here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/publish#testaccounts)
In publishing page, i left the trusted testers dropdown empty and clicked "Publish to trusted testers". Now as described in help center, i added one email ID as trusted tester. 
Everything works fine, the user able to access the extension in webstore via direct url.
But the problem is, now I removed the user email id from my trusted tester list, but that User is still be able to access the extension. Tried sign-out sign-in but the user still able to access the extension using the URL.

How do I stop that user accessing my extension?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to `unpublish` your extension. Then "Publish to trusted testers" again with different email ID.